# How open Wordpress posts in fancy box?

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

How I can open Wordpress posts in fancy box?

Eg:
*Lorem ipsum LINK lorem ipsum.*

When I click on LINK - how to open some post in fancybox or other "popup" like Litghbox etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `thickbox` js provided by wordpress for creating fancybox as like :

```
<?php add_thickbox(); ?>
<div id="my-content-id" style="display:none;">
     <p>
          This is my hidden content! It will appear in ThickBox when the link is clicked.
     </p>
</div>

<a href="#TB_inline?width=600&height=550&inlineId=my-content-id" class="thickbox">View my inline content!</a>
```

For more details, check out here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/ThickBox

**Edit:**

For loading content from another source or site.

```
<?php add_thickbox(); ?>
<a href="http://example.com?TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550" class="thickbox">View the WordPress Codex!</a>
```

Comment: Yes, but it show only div...
I want show content of other post (or other site) in fancy box :)

Comment: So, we are very near :) 
But...
http://galeriagrebocin.pl/oferta/
Click on map in "11 | 807,8" - page in tickbox is loading...

Comment: try the href as like `http://google.pl?TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550` instead of simple `http://google.pl`

Comment: do You have other options? :)